# Add a printer script

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scripting, printing

We  have an old print server that is going to be taken offline because the hardware is starting to fail, and we now have a Print Server system running virtually. The old servers name is different  than the new because of a new naming convention that has been pushed down by managment, so I would like to write a script that would add new printer that point to the new print server and remove the old printer that points to the old print server.

Comment: From your tags it appears your server is windows 2008, what are your clients?

Comment: XP maybe 7 at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to be running 2008 server you could deploy your printers with Group Policies.  This may be easier then writing a script.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722179%28WS.10%29.aspx